# How to add new page when value changes from a statement using TCPDF

Tags: php, mysql, tcpdf

I'm trying out TCPDF and have it working well. The problem now is having a control of writing data on a new page once a value changes. The select statement given below groups the employees based on employee id and once this employee id changes, the information should be written on a new page.

```
    // -------------------------START--------------------------------
    require_once("header.php");

            $tbl_header = '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" width="100%" border="1">';
            $tbl_footer = '</table>';
            $tbl ='';

            //statement one
            $result = $odb -> query('select * from employee group by EmployeeID');
            if($result->rowcount() > 0) {
                foreach ($result as $row) {
                                $EmployeeID = $row['EmployeeID']; 
                                $EmployeeName = $row['EmployeeName']; 


             $tbl = '<tr>
              <td width="50%" align="right">Emp ID:<br/> '.$EmployeeID.' </td>
              <td  width="50%" align="right">Emp Name:<br/> '.$EmployeeName.' </td> 
              </tr>';
                }   
                }

            //statement two 
            require_once("headerb.php");
            $query = $db -> query('select * from income group by EmployeeID');
                  if($query->rowcount() > 0) {
                        foreach ($query as $rowb) {
                            $Code  = $rowb['Code'];
                            $IncomeName  = $rowb['IncomeName'];
                            $IncomeAmount  = $rowb['IncomeAmount'];


                          $tblb .= '<tr>
              <td width="20%" align="right">'.$Code.' </td>
              <td  width="40%" align="left">'.$IncomeName.' </td> 
              <td width="40%" align="right">'.$IncomeAmount.' </td>
              </tr>';
                        }
                  }


            //I was thinking of something like this

            //$pdf->AddPage();
            //$pdf->writeHTML($tbl_header. $tbl .$tblb . $tbl_footer, true, false, false, false, '');

            //Forcing to break page on change of value
            //If next $EmployeeID is not equal to previous, output records on new page

            if ($EmployeeID <> $EmployeeID)
                {
                $pdf->AddPage();
                $pdf->writeHTML($tbl_header. $tbl .$tblb . $tbl_footer, true, false, false, false, '');
                }

            //Or

            for ($k=0; $k < $EmployeeID; $k++) {
            $pdf->AddPage();
            $pdf->writeHTML($tbl_header. $tbl .$tblb . $tbl_footer, true, false, false, false, '');

            if ($k < $EmployeeID) {
            $pdf->AddPage();
            $pdf->writeHTML($tbl_header. $tbl .$tblb . $tbl_footer, true, false, false, false, '');
                }
             }
            /////------------------------------------END------------------------

            $pdf->Output(__DIR__ .'/paid_'.date('m-d-Y_hia').'.pdf', 'FI');
```

Am really stuck on how I can write the logic of breaking page to write on a new one once a different Employee ID is reached/received

Comment: What happens with what you already have? In what way is it not working? Checking to see if the employee ID has changed would seem to be the correct logic to determine whether or not to start a new page.

Comment: Yes @Dave, thats the logic I need help on. What I have now prints all the details right after the other without breaking into a different page once Employee ID changes. Any luck?

Comment: This line `if ($EmployeeID <> $EmployeeID)` will never be true. Stash the Employee ID at the bottom of your foreach then compare that stored value to the current Employee ID. If they are different start a new page. You'll need to initialize the variable you use to stash the ID to avoid an error the first time through the `foreach`.